HTML canvas: additional stroke after restore
Consider the following piece of code (test it yourself):


function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(75, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Outer circle
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.moveTo(75, 75);

  ctx.save();
  ctx.setLineDash([3, 3]);
  ctx.lineTo(90, 90);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
  
  //ctx.stroke();
}

draw();
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>



It plots this:

However, if I uncomment the last ctx.stroke(), it draws a line on top of the dashed one, not sure if from (75, 75) to (90, 90) or the other way around:


function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(75, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Outer circle
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.moveTo(75, 75);

  ctx.save();
  ctx.setLineDash([3, 3]);
  ctx.lineTo(90, 90);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

  ctx.stroke();
}

draw()
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>




I thought saving and restoring didn't affect the "path cursor", and there's either any "pending draw command", and so I expected the extra (and accidental) stroke after restore don't have any effect whatsoever.
What is going on exactly and how does save()/restore() relate to this?

I answer myself. The reason of that effect turned out to have nothing to do with save and restore, but with stroke. If you call stroke repeatedly, you draw the path repeatedly, like if the last stroke didn't "clear it up", so the path is still available to keep growing or adding more pieces to it.
In my example above, the second stroke just had a different dash style, and so the second stroke was applied with other settings.
In this other simpler example, I draw an almost transparent path, and as I added more and more calls to stroke, the path was progressively less transparent:


function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
  ctx.moveTo(75, 75);
  ctx.lineTo(90, 90);
  ctx.lineTo(100, 120);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.stroke();
}

draw()
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>




save() and restore() only saves the canvas drawing state, it does not saves/restores the actual line (with eg lineTo and stroke).
So your last stroke is still affected by the lineTo called before.


The drawing state that gets saved onto a stack consists of:

The current transformation matrix.

The current clipping region.

The current dash list.

The current values of the following attributes:
strokeStyle, fillStyle, globalAlpha, lineWidth, lineCap, lineJoin, miterLimit, lineDashOffset, shadowOffsetX, shadowOffsetY, shadowBlur, shadowColor, globalCompositeOperation, font, textAlign, textBaseline, direction, imageSmoothingEnabled




Does it means that all "drawing commands" will be repeated after restoring? I don't understand. I don't see the logic behind it.

Repeated isn't the correct word choose, but only the state is restored, eg; color etc. If you draw something between save/restore, that won't be removed.

What's the meaning of "lineTo" then? It's very confusing that if I'm writting in a piece of paper and temporarily change the pen to get one with a different color, I get two lines in my paper. I only draw a line once.

Please refer to the docs about lineTo. If you call lineTo 3 times, before calling stroke; you'll end up with 3 lines.
